# Using ES6 Promises in Mongoose code

Tags: node.js, mongoose, typescript

I am trying to use ES6 Promises for Mongoose ODM in TypeScrpt.

I have the following line

```
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
```

Which give me the following error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'PromiseConstructor' is not assignable to type 'typeof Promise'.
  Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>'.
    Property 'end' is missing in type 'Promise<any>'.
```

Comment: I am following the instructions on Mongoose website, http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html IT seems like typescript compiler is not happy with something.

Comment: And keep in mind that Mongoose may require a more full-featured implementation of the Promises spec than it gets in native `Promise`. The vanilla implementation is extremely basic.

Comment: The `require('mongoose').Promise = Promise;` work well for me under node `v5.3.0`, what is your node version?

Comment: I am using v5.6.0 - It looks like the issue is caused by typescript compiler the final code, if compiles, should work as @zangw pointed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the ES6 Native `promise` to mongoose `promise`:

```
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
```

You get the error

> Property 'end' is missing in type 'Promise'.

Because the native Promise *is missing the property* `end` which is *present in mongoose Promise* (docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/mpromise).

## Workaround

You can either:

- Hack the mongoose definition to lie and say its a `ES6 Promise` instead of `mpromise`
- Or Suppress the error:

  ```
  mongoose.Promise = Promise as any;
  ```
- Or not do this entirely :)

Comment: Moongose now (5.2.7) support native ES Promise. [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#built-in-promises)